# Restore implementation after mocking jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a function and after testing use the real implementation for other tests.

```
const myService = () => {
    return {
      foo: () => return 1;
    }
}
```

```
const myService = require('./myService.js');

jest.mock('./myService');

describe('testing myService', () => {
  it('should return 2 by mocked', () => {
    myService.mockImplementation(() => ({
      foo: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(2),
    }));
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(myService().foo()).toBe(2);
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return 1', () => {
    expect(myService().foo()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

But after this, foo() is still mocked.

Answer (score 0):

[jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) is a better choice to create a mock method for an object.

We can restore the method to original implementation by using `jest.restoreAllMocks()` inside `afterEach()` hook.

> Beware that `jest.restoreAllMocks()` only works when the mock was created with `jest.spyOn`; other mocks will require you to manually restore them.

E.g.

`myService.js`:

```js
const myService = () => {
  return {
    foo: () => 1,
  };
};
module.exports = myService;
```

`myService.test.js`:

```js
const myService = require('./myService.js');

describe('testing myService', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return 2 by mocked', () => {
    const service = myService();
    jest.spyOn(service, 'foo').mockReturnValueOnce(2);
    expect(service.foo()).toBe(2);
    expect(service.foo).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
  it('should return 1', () => {
    const service = myService();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(service.foo)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(service.foo()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68459394/myService.test.js (8.465 s)
  testing myService
    ✓ should return 2 by mocked (3 ms)
    ✓ should return 1

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.548 s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a mock function in Jest while retaining a reference to the original implementation, you can use the following utility function:

```js
/**
 * Creates a mock function and attaches the original implementation to the mock object.
 *
 * @param {Function} fn - The original function to be mocked.
 * @returns {Function} A Jest mock function with the original implementation attached.
 */
const createMock = (fn) => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    mockFn.mock.original = fn;
    return mockFn;
};
```

Example of Usage:

Consider you have a db.js module with two functions, getOrder and updateOrder:

```js
// db.js
const getOrder = (orderId) => {
    return { id: orderId, price: 100 };
};

const updateOrder = (order) => {
    console.log('order updated successfully!');
    return order;
};

module.exports = {
    getOrder,
    updateOrder,
};
```

To mock the getOrder function and later restore it, you can do the following:

```js
// Mock the getOrder function
db.getOrder = createMock(db.getOrder).mockReturnValue({
    id: 1,
    price: 20,
});

// ... Perform your tests using the mocked function ...

// Restore the original implementation
db.getOrder = db.getOrder.mock.original;
```